# how to put a textinputlayout programmatically in my auto generated edittext

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to put a `TextInputLayout` in my auto generated `EditText`.

Example: if I click the `Button`, the app will generate a `Spinner` and `EditText` and I want to put a `TextInputLayout` on my `EditText`.

```
btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    tr = new TableRow(this);
    _spinner = new Spinner(this);
    _td1 = new EditText(this);
    _td2 = new EditText(this);
    TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
    _td1.SetHint(Resource.String.qty);
    _td2.SetHint(Resource.String.unit);
    //textInputLayout.AddView(_td1);
    //textInputLayout.AddView(_td2);
    //_td1.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.EditDesign);
    //_td2.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.EditDesign);
    //_spinner.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.EditTxtStyle);
    ArrayAdapter<string> _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, prodList);
    _spinner.Adapter = _adapter;
    tr.AddView(textInputLayout);
    tr.AddView(_spinner);
    tr.AddView(_td1);
    tr.AddView(_td2);
    tbleLayout.AddView(tr);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TextInputLayout** is a new addition to 22.2.0 that is used in conjunction with **EditText**(or a subclass of EditText) and can **only contain one subclass of EditText(or a subclass of EditText)**：

your code is basically correct，you should change like this:

```
 button.Click += (sender, e) =>
     {
         tr = new TableRow(this);
         _spinner = new Spinner(this);
         _td1 = new EditText(this);
         _td2 = new EditText(this);
         TextInputLayout textInputLayout1 = new TextInputLayout(this);
         TextInputLayout textInputLayout2 = new TextInputLayout(this);
         _td1.SetHint(Resource.String.qty);
         _td2.SetHint(Resource.String.unit);
        ArrayAdapter<string> _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, prodList);
        _spinner.Adapter = _adapter;
        textInputLayout1.AddView(_td1);
        textInputLayout2.AddView(_td2);
        tr.AddView(textInputLayout);
        tr.AddView(_spinner);
        tbleLayout.AddView(tr);
    };
```